# self stop from a infinite php while loop with unexpected time

Tags: php, time

i have this infinite while loop in my php script runs every second but i will eventually stop.
I've tried change the value or comment out the max execution time from php.ini, or even put a set_time_limit(9999); in my php script and i still stop after a unexpected time, few seconds or a minute! where else can i set this time limit to support infinite looping time?

Comment: Keep in mind, PHP was not designed to run for a long time. You may get unexpected memory leaks. I've had experience with a PHP script running fine for a long time, and then suddenly consume all available memory on the machine, locking up the server.

Answer (score 1):

Run your script from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

while (true) {
  set_time_limit(10); // 10 seconds allowed to reach next iteration
  usleep(1000);
}
```

Should work just fine? Also check your memory consumption. Enable error logging so you can see if your script stops because of an error…

Answer (score 0):

Which web server you use? 
If you run it on remote hosting It may be problem frontend web server such as lighttpd.
No solution in this situation.